# Change cylinder box for a cube box

Tags: graphics3d, vector, boxes

I have a vector field where all vectors are contained in a cylinder.  I  want to see the shape of this cylinder. I could see a cubic box if I would change `Boxed->True`, but the shape of the box is cubic!!

Any help?

```
    table = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/rjM2i5Jt", "Table", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True];
X = table[[;; , ;; 3]];
V = table[[;; , 4 ;; 6]];
Graphics3D[{Arrowheads@.015, {If[Subtract@@#[[;;,3]] <= 0, Red, Blue], 
     Arrow[#]}& /@ Transpose[{X, X + .07 Normalize /@ V}]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X = table[[;; , ;; 3]];
V = table[[;; , 4 ;; 6]];
Graphics3D[{
  {Opacity[0.5], Cylinder[{{0, 0, .4}, {0, 0, 1}}, .43]},
  Arrowheads@.015, {If[Subtract @@ #[[;; , 3]] <= 0, Red, Blue], 
     Arrow[#]} & /@ Transpose[{X, X + .07 Normalize /@ V}]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```